# Unable to display shape legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following code :

```html
cols <- c("Bonus"=maroon ,
            "Limit"=grey)
  

a <- ggplot(periodtreatments, aes(x=names, width=.2)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=bonus_coefs, colour="Bonus"), stat="identity", position = position_nudge(x = -.1), shape=16) +
  geom_point(aes(y=limit_coefs, colour="Limit"), stat="identity", position = position_nudge(x = .1), shape=15)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=bonus_upper, ymax=bonus_lower,  width=0.09), size =0.8, stat="identity", colour=maroon, position = position_nudge(x = -.1)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=limit_lower, ymax=limit_upper,  width=0.09), size =0.8, stat="identity", colour=grey, position=position_nudge(x = .1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Treatment effect (minutes/day)") +
  theme_classic() + 
  #theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "")  +
  theme(legend.text.align = 0,
        legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"),
        legend.position="bottom") +
  theme(legend.margin=margin(0,0,0,0),
        legend.box.margin=margin(-10,-10,-10,-10))  +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black"))  +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-70, 5)) +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=11))  +
    theme( # remove the vertical grid lines
           panel.grid.major.x = element_blank() ,
           # explicitly set the horizontal lines (or they will disappear too)
           panel.grid.major.y = element_line( size=.05, color="grey" ) 
    )+ 
  scale_colour_manual(name = "", values=cols, 
                      labels = c("Bonus", "Limit"))+
   scale_shape_manual(name = "",
                     labels = c("Bonus", "Limit"),
                     values = c(16, 15))
```

But the "scale_shape_manual" legend does not work.
In fact here is what my plot look like
Why does the Bonus show as a sqaure whereas its shape is 16 = point ???
Please help me i am so helpless
[image]

Comment: `Error: object 'periodtreatments' not found`, I can't reproduce this at the moment.

Comment: In general, you only get a legend for an aesthetic if it is inside `aes()`. So you could treat `shape` like `color` by setting to a constant inside `aes()` and then set the shapes you want in `scale_shape_manual()`. Another option would be to use `override.aes` as in the given answer, using the two shapes in a vector.